# Windows Identity Foundation does not officially support SAML 2.0; use WIF CTP or stick with SAML 1.1?

Tags: single-sign-on, wif, saml, saml-2.0

We would like to use SAML 2.0 for a Single Sign On solution. As a typical Microsoft shop, we prefer to use Microsoft components as much as possible. Windows Identity Foundation supports SAML 2.0, but the extension is still in Community Technology Preview (CTP) for more than a year, with no information anywhere on future course. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alikl/archive/2011/05/16/windows-identity-foundation-wif-extension-for-saml-2-0-protocol-community-technology-preview-ctp.aspx

I came across an inspiring article by Michèle Bustamante: http://www.devproconnections.com/article/federated-security/generate-saml-tokens-using-windows-identity-foundation  She actively promotes WIF + SAML 2.0, but nowhere in the article she talks about CTP or final release. Neither could I reach her for a clarification.

With this background, is it safe to use WIF Community Technology Preview for SAML 2.0 or stick with SAML 1.1? Does SAML 2.0 offer significant advantage over SAML 1.1? Is the future of SAML 1.1 in question?

Any other alternatives?

Answer (score 4):

You should clarify whether you're talking about SAML 2.0 protocol (e.g SAMLP) or just the token type. WIF RTM supports SAML 2.0 tokens, but not SAMLP.

So if it's just SAML 2.0 token support you need, WIF RTM is sufficient, though WIF extensions CTP does add some SAMLP support.

If you're looking for a SAMLP solution and you're a Microsoft shop then you should consider ADFS 2.0.

ADFS 2.0 would do "protocol transition": it will talk SAMLP with the Identity Provider and WS-Federation with your app (both use SAML "Tokens"). WIF supports WS-Federation.

Comment: Thanks! We would like to have our own Identity Provider (STS may be?) where the Authentication store is a MS SQL Server. So I guess we cannot use ADFS 2.0? Since it can use only AD as Authentication store? 

Regarding SAML 2.0 Protocol VS Tokens: I meant the protocol.

Comment: That's correct, ADFS 2.0 requires an AD account store, but you can configure ADFS to use custom attribute stores. Supposing you authenticated a user in AD, you could populate additional user claims from a SQL database for example: http://www.syfuhs.net/post/2010/09/14/Claims-Transformation-and-Custom-Attribute-Stores-in-Active-Directory-Federation-Services-2.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Identity Server](http://identityserver.codeplex.com/) which is a STS that does use SQL Server for authentication. You can easily federate this with ADFS.

From what I remember about reading the licence agreement for the CTP release, it's just out there for comment - you can't use it e.g. in a Production environment.

As per @Eugenio, WIF only supports WS-Federation.

How were you intending to "stick with SAML 1.1"?

**Update:** What I suggest is that you use Identity Server to do the authentication against the DB. Your WIF applications are bound using FedUtil to Identity Server. You then federate Identity Server with ADFS. Your external parties use SAML to talk to ADFS and ADFS will handle the plumbing to enable them to authenticate with the Identity Server DB.

Note that WIF doesn't support SAML at all.

Comment: Thanks. Since Identity Server [cannot support SAML Protocol](http://identityserver.codeplex.com/discussions/354152), I am a bit stranded! 
Of course 3rd party alternatives like [ComponentSource](http://www.componentspace.com/Products/SAMLv20.aspx) supports both SAML Tokens & Protocols, but then I'll be forcing our external applications which are planning to use our SSO also to buy ComponentSource, & they'll not be happy about it. Is WS-Federation the way to go? It doesn't seem to have a good reputation [against SAML](http://www.terena.org/activities/tf-emc2/meetings/9/slides/SAML&WS.ppt)