# ADFS 2.0 protocol transition

Tags: asp.net-mvc, saml-2.0, adfs2.0

In the below article, i have seen something called "Protocol transition" by ADFS 2.0.

[Windows Identity Foundation does not officially support SAML 2.0; use WIF CTP or stick with SAML 1.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11342186/windows-identity-foundation-does-not-officially-support-saml-2-0-use-wif-ctp-or?rq=1)

What is the best way to do protocol transition in ADFS 2.0

Comment: This question is far too broad in scope, and asking for the *best way* is entirely opinion-based. This site is for *specific questions* about problems you're facing, not broadly scoped, vague posts.

Answer (score 0):

What is your use case?

As per the article, you meed to clarify whether you are referring to the SAML protocol or SAML XML tokens.

WIF does not support the SAML protocol.

The "transition" mentioned is simply using ADFS to provide the SAML support.

Application --> WS-Fed protocol --> ADFS --> SAML protocol to somewhere.